# How to change Login screen to Kde

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I installed kubuntu-desktop in Ubuntu 14.04. In the installation, it didn't ask me to choose default login screen. Now my login screen is still Ubuntu login. How can I change it to Kde login screen and make it as default?

I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

open below file:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

and change line user-session to what session you want to set it as default session (default is "ubuntu" for Ubuntu 14.04)

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
```

You can get all installed session on your Ubuntu with the following command:

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/

gnome.desktop
kde-plasma.desktop
ubuntu.desktop
xfce.desktop
xubuntu.desktop
```