# How Can I Restore The Default Login Manager for KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, login-screen, sddm

I recently installed the `unity-desktop` not knowing that it would change my login manager, and that KDE & Unity generally don't play well together. How can I restore the default KDE login manager for Kubuntu 17.04? I believe that it is SDDM, but I'm not sure.

Comment: While I still feel a clean install of whichever flavor is the best route, please check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/580207/how-to-change-login-screen-to-kde,  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/choose-switch-linux-display-managers/ and http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to reconfigure the sddm package with the command:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm

A list should appear asking for the default login manager, select sddm and the login manager should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Previous command didn't work for me. The following worked :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-breeze
```

Source : [What methods are there to restore a deleted theme? file:///usr/share/sddm//themes/breeze/Main.qml:No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110142/what-methods-are-there-to-restore-a-deleted-theme-file-usr-share-sddm-theme)