# What methods are there to restore a deleted theme? file:///usr/share/sddm//themes/breeze/Main.qml:No such file or directory

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, themes, restore

I'm very new to Linux. I rather like Kubuntu 18.04, but today I managed to break it. Using Discover, I deleted laptop battery controls and hastily agreed to remove a long list of dependencies.

[Someone did it similar a couple months ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084157/kubuntu-shows-error-at-login-file-usr-share-sddm-themes-breeze-main-qmlno/1110073?noredirect=1#comment1832047_1110073), but I think their solution to use SSH won't work because I hadn't set one up.

What other methods can I employ to reverse or repair what I've done?
Here's what I've got going for me that I think might help.

1. I previously paired my phone with KDE connect, but can't find the computer when it's booted though.
2. I had installed Timeshift and have several backups on the harddrive.
3. I can remove my afflicted desktop harddrive and connect it to a raspberry pi running Raspian.

I would prefer to avoid a fresh install because I don't want to shy away from a learning opportunity. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's not clear what access you have. Console? Nothing at all? It's possible that you have already learned the most important lesson: No handrails, read the output before proceeding.

Comment: Friendly tip: avoid Discover for installing/removing software and stick to the command line: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I couldn't gain access to terminal yesterday, but this morning I switched keyboards after reading about someone having an issue with their laptop. I am not using a laptop, but got me thinking, I've got all these keyboards around, let's try another one. Sure enough, I got into virtual console and was able to reinstall the theme and plasma desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=breeze%2FMain.qml) gives me the package name - `sddm-theme-breeze` which contains */usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/Main.qml* file.

You need to reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-breeze
```